# Failed to copy Xml as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, clone

I am working on as3 project in which i am using XML.I am facing an issue when I copy an xml object to other (newxml=oldxml) the text is copied but if I delete some node from oldxml It automatically delete that node from copied variable (newxml).

Code for deleting node:

```
for each( node in xmlold.links.slidelink.(@displaytext.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchbar.text.toLowerCase())<0))
{

var index = node.childIndex();



   delete xmlold.links.slidelink[index];
   }

    this.display.text=xmlnew.toString();
```

Now when I display text if "xmlnew" It give me output after deleted text which is not required

Xml Look like:

```
<outline xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <links>
    <slidelink slideid="_player" displaytext="Headd"    <slidelink slideid="5pnZ9Eziqq4" displaytext="Relationship" expand="true" type="slide"/>
    <slidelink slideid="vgVg68B" displaytext="Temperature Relationship" expand="true" type="slide"/>
    <slidelink slideid="_player" displaytext="Viscosity" expand="true" type="slide"/>
  </links>
</outline>
```

Please check the problem Your help will really appreciated thanks

Comment: `newxml=oldxml` does not copy, it simply says "**newxml is same thing as oldxml**"... you need something like `newxml = new XML (oldxml);`. You can check google or the AS3 manual on how to pass oldxml data into newxml but as a starting point try `var newxml : XML = new XML ( oldxml.toXMLString() );` and fix any issues from there onwards

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this is also not working kindly help me

Comment: Solved! your trick did the magic Great Vc one.Thank you so much.I am new here can you tell me how to mark your answer as corrected. Thanks once again :)

Comment: You can't mark a comment as accepted, you can upvote it though.

Comment: How to upvote? Where is the option?

Comment: @Papa'sDoll I've put it an answer so now you can mark that as accepted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newxml=oldxml` does not copy, it simply says "newxml is same thing as oldxml".

You need something like `newxml = new XML (oldxml);`

As a starting point try:

```
var newxml : XML = new XML ( oldxml.toXMLString() );
```

Comment: This works, but it's unnecessarily expensive. Converting your XML to a string then parsing the string back to XML is very slow. You should just use XML `copy()`, which is provided in the API so you *don't* have to re-parse the XML like this.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to copy an XML structure is to use [`XML/copy()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#copy()), which is exactly what it's for.

```
var newXML:XML = oldXML.copy();
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but the problem is already solved.This solution is good too.

Comment: You're welcome to accept any answer, but you "should" be using `copy()` to copy XML. Using `new XML` will result in expensive string parsing, which is very slow, which is why XML `copy()` is provided in the API.

Comment: Hence my "You can check the AS3 manual on how to pass oldxml data into newxml but as a starting point try..." either way gives same result for the Asker. Check **[toXMLString](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#toXMLString())** as you can see it copies the data (complex or not)..

Comment: @VC.One The difference is that `toXMLString()` converts the XML to a String, then `XML()` parses the entire XML string back to XML. This is both slow and pointless, you should avoid re-parsing, that's *exactly* why `copy()` exists. It's like using `a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b))` as opposed to just `a = b.copy()`.

Comment: @Aaron, excuse the late reply I aint logged in for a week. My final say on this is.. I'm not convinced by it's "very slow and expensive" (it shouldnt even be slightly slow). I think you're **over-estimating** the complexity of parsing XML and **under-estimating** a CPU's ability to crunch through UTF encoded text. Trace original `XML` and compare that to trace of `XML.copy` and trace of `toXMLString`. All 3 look exactly the same and will remain the same in memory. Repeating / process any memory data is instant for a computer.

Comment: @VC.One Nope, that's not right. They result in the same thing but XML parsing is absolutely **slower** than `copy()` and don't have the same memory usage. A quick test shows `copy()` is over 5 times as fast as parsing XML. That's not surprising, because parsing is always slow compared to in-memory copy operations. Will it make a practical difference for a small bit of XML? No. But they are different and you absolutely "should" use `copy()` instead of re-parsing the entire XML document when you don't have to, *that's the whole point of `copy()`*.